# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) - using gsl_matrix_set

Tags: c, runtime-error, gsl

I am trying to use the GSL library in C and am running into trouble.

I am allocating space for my matrices and vectors:

```
A   = gsl_matrix_alloc(nr, nc); /* Data matrix */
tau = gsl_vector_alloc(nc);     /* required place holder for GSL */
```

Then I am initializing `A`:

```
for(i = 0; i < nr; i++){
  gsl_matrix_set(A, i, 0, 1.0); 
}

for(i = 1; i < nr; i++){
  for(j = 0; j < nc; j++){
    gsl_matrix_set(A, i, j, 1.0 / (double)(i + j + 1)); 
  }
}
```

I am then erroring on this line:

```
gsl_linalg_QR_decomp(A, tau);
```

with the following error:

```
==901== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==901==    at 0x3E8920AE0E: cblas_dnrm2 (in /usr/lib64/libgslcblas.so.0.0.0)
==901==    by 0x3E88EA779A: gsl_linalg_householder_transform (in /usr/lib64/libgsl.so.0.14.0)
==901==    by 0x3E88EA1305: gsl_linalg_QR_decomp (in /usr/lib64/libgsl.so.0.14.0)
==901==    by 0x400FF3: GE_FindPoint (hw8.c:145)
==901==    by 0x400DF4: main (hw8.c:66)
==901==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==901==    at 0x4A06A2E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==901==    by 0x3E88E4CFD4: gsl_block_alloc (in /usr/lib64/libgsl.so.0.14.0)
==901==    by 0x3E88EB1768: gsl_matrix_alloc (in /usr/lib64/libgsl.so.0.14.0)
==901==    by 0x400EBB: GE_FindPoint (hw8.c:110)
==901==    by 0x400DF4: main (hw8.c:66)
```

Line 110 points to the line allocating `A`: `A   = gsl_matrix_alloc(nr, nc);`

In this case, `nc = 3` and `nr = 3840`. What would cause this error?

Comment: I don't know gsl, but the initialization looks strange to me. `gsl_matrix_set( A, i, 0, ... )` is called twice for 1 <= i < nr and `gsl_matrix_set( A, 0, j, ... )` is never called for 1 <= j < nc: Maybe it should be `for( i=0;...)` and `for( j=1;...)` in the second loop

Comment: That seems to get rid of the error!

Comment: If it's so, should I post it as an answer?

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Sure! I'll mark resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second part of your initialization, the start values of `i` and `j` are mismatched. So you call `gsl_matrix_set( A, i, 0, ... )` twice for 1 <= i < nr and you never call `gsl_matrix_set( A, 0, j, ... )` for 1 <= j < nc.

Just change that part of the initialization to

```
for(i = 0; i < nr; i++){
   for(j = 1; j < nc; j++){
      gsl_matrix_set(A, i, j, 1.0 / (double)(i + j + 1)); 
   }  
}
```